# Manipulating and extracting JSON Values from REST API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, nlp

Here is a sample of the Parsed JSON from the REST API

```
{
    "sentence": "In 2009, Elliot Turner launched AlchemyAPI to process the written word, with all of its quirks and nuances, and got immediate traction.",
    "subject": {
        "text": "Elliot Turner",
        "entities": [{
            "type": "Person",
            "text": "Elliot Turner"
        }],
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "Elliot Turner"
        }]
    },
    "action": {
        "text": "to process",
        "lemmatized": "to process",
        "verb": {
            "text": "process",
            "tense": "future"
        }
    },
    "object": {
        "text": "the written word, with all of its quirks and nuances",
        "sentiment": {
            "type": "positive",
            "score": "0.338433"
        },
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "nuances"
        }, {
            "text": "quirks"
        }, {
            "text": "written word"
        }]
    }
}
```

Can I create a java code to get the keywords and remove it from the sentence like this one:

> In 2009, Elliot Turner launched AlchemyAPI to process the written word, with all of its quirks and nuances, and got immediate traction.

Into this one:

> In 2009, ______________ launched AlchemyAPI to process the written word, with all of its quirks and nuances, and got immediate traction.

a) Elliot Turner

Comment: yes, you can, but what do you want, the working code? this is not how StackOverflow works..

Comment: This seems like a homework to me.

Comment: not the working code, i have some code of mine already. thanks